# Parallelizing independent actions on the same DataFrame in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have a Spark `DataFrame` with the following schema:

```
root
 | -- prob: Double
 | -- word: String
```

I'd like to randomly select two different words from this `DataFrame`, but I'd like to perform this action X amount of times, so at the end I'll have X tuples of words selected at random, and of course every selection id independent of each other. How do I accomplish this?

**EXAMPLE:**

Let's say this is my data-set:

```
[(0.1,"blue"),(0.2,"yellow"),(0.1,"red"),(0.6,"green")]
```

where the first number id `prob` and the second is the `word`. For X=5 the output will be:

```
1. blue, green
2. green, yellow
3. green, yellow
4. yellow, blue
5. green, red
```

As they are independent actions, you can see that 2 and 3 are the same, and that's fine. But in every tuple, a word can only repeat once.

Comment: hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39345502/1025328) helps

Comment: Not too much :/ it's about taking n rows from a dataset once, while I need to do this several times in parallel

Comment: @shakedzy how it is different in your case?

Comment: This is not clear to me. Can you be more specific please ? With an example maybe.

Comment: @addmeaning this is different because in my case, the same word can be selected for more than one tuple, as the different selections are independent. In this example, If I select 2*X rows, each row can only be selected once

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Randomly according to what distribution? Do you want prob to be used here? How many pairs do you need as a fraction of total? How many records do you have?

Comment: `prob` is used, yes. uniform distribution. X pairs and Y records (numbers are unknown).

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use one of this DataFrame methods:

- `randomSplit(weights: Array[Double], seed: Long)`
- `randomSplitAsList(weights: Array[Double], seed: Long)` or
- `sample(withReplacement: Boolean, fraction: Double)`

and then take first two Rows.

2) Shuffle rows and take first two of them.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
dataset.orderBy(rand()).limit(n)
```

3) Or you can use `takeSample` method of the RDD and then convert it to a DataFrame:

```
def takeSample(
      withReplacement: Boolean,
      num: Int,
      seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): Array[T]
```

For example:

```
dataframe.rdd.takeSample(true, 1000).toDF()
```

Comment: What you mentioned is the process of getting one tuple of words - I need to repeat this process several times. If I repeat this process in a loop, will Spark parallelize it, or do it one by one?

Comment: Each iteration of a loop will be done in parallel, but I don't think that Spark will parallelize all loop process.

Comment: Is there a way of making it parallelize the loops too? I mean, they are independent, so it's a waste doing it as a sequence..