# PySpark: How do I fix 'function' object has no attribute 'rand' error?

Tags: debugging, random, pyspark, databricks, attributeerror

I am trying to randomly select 100 rows from my PySpark Dataframe. For that I would like to use the code as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344769/spark-dataframe-select-n-random-rows):

```
training_data= data.orderBy(F.rand()).limit(100)
```

However I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rand'
```

I imported rand() the following way:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand as F
```

I tried to import rand the same way as decribed in the post, but I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'
```

I also tried to use the function just as such:

```
training_data= data.orderBy(rand()).limit(100)
```

But then I get the following name error:

```
NameError: name 'rand' is not defined
```

Does anyone know how to fix it ? I am new to PySpark and I think I am missing something obvious here. Note that I am working on Databricks.

Thank you

Comment: First do `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`. Then you can use `F.rand()`

Comment: Ok I will try that, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I actually managed to achieve what I wanted by doing the following:

```
training_data, test_data = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed = 100)
```