# Hive: how to get global ordering with sort by

Tags: hive, sql-order-by

`order by` has only one reducer, so slow.I'm trying to find a fast way.`sort by` sorts in each reducer,then how can we get global ordering?
I got this by search engine:

```
select * from 
(select title,cast(price as FLOAT) p from tablename 
distribute by time 
sort by p desc 
limit 10 ) t 
order by t.p desc 
limit 10;
```

Then try to validate it.
1.Get right answer in my hive table.There are **215666** records in the table named tablename.

```
SELECT title,cast(price as FLOAT) p
from tablename 
WHERE dt='2020-03-08'
and price IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY p DESC
LIMIT 10
;
```

2.Use the searched clause.

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
set mapred.reduce.tasks=5; 
SELECT title,cast(price as FLOAT) p
from tablename
WHERE dt='2020-03-08'
and price IS NOT NULL
DISTRIBUTE BY title
SORT BY p desc
LIMIT 10
;
```

The result is the same as the right answer!
Here are my questions:
1.Why only return 10 lines? There are 5 reducer, each reducer returns 10, should be 5*10=50?
2.If should return 10 lines, why the result is global ordering? This 10 line is not from the same reducer ? The [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802115/is-limit-clause-in-hive-really-random) is random, it cannot get global order in 5 reducer.
3.If should return 10 lines, the outer part in the searched clause is redundant?

```
select * from 
(
) t 
order by t.p desc 
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `total order partitioner`, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseBulkLoad#HBaseBulkLoad-PrepareRangePartitioning for details (just ignore part with HBase)